# Restore built-in list styles gallery

Tags: microsoft-word, restore, styles, list

I removed the list styles and can't get them back.
I have tried restoring the global template Normal.dotm, but it doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First, see the following two parallel articles that show the best way to use bullets and numbering in Word.

- [**How to create outline numbering in Word**](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) by Shauna Kelly, Word MVP
- [**How to control bullets in Microsoft Word**](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html) by Shauna Kelly, Word MVP

She advises avoiding use of that gallery completely. *Most Word experts agree that the methods shown in these articles are the key to having durable numbering or bullets in Word documents. You will find them referenced in just about every question online about numbering.*

Your styles are still there, just the gallery has been disrupted. Again, you probably do not want to be using that gallery. However...

### In direct answer to your question: Find and delete the file `listgal.dat`.